Is There a Wuala Alternative That Lets You Share Local Space to Expand Storage Across Private and Public Clouds?
I'm looking for a free solution that would allow me to store 2+ TiB in the cloud for free by sharing aka keeping local storage online for other users to use. Wuala[x] was built like this, with private and public distributed groups and forums that would allow users to share data, to store it, to access it, it had a video player embedded and it was just a dream come true for millions of users.
From what I remember the architecture of Wuala was like so: the user would share say 6 GiB and then they would have access to 6+ GiB in the Wuala cloud. What made the interesting math problem was that they would replicate the data 6 times for high availability so that if a user would close their laptop over the night, the data would still be available in 5 other places. And it was written in Java, not the speediest of languages but portable.
Video presentation of the architecture of Wuala from its creators
https://mega.nz/file/O5kTlRYR#LmZaH0i8XUKF49X-2h8TZ6t-r2gEiHrPtSeTE3rfBiU

And a demo
https://mega.nz/file/DsNnFLwR#5DM9eONX9f99zzXIkZ4oZcXI2Q-aZMrhFLepNusqhVk

Maybe a guru of AutoGPT[i] with Ollama[ii] offline AI models can build a better Freeware, Open Source version based on the text description of the video extracted with Whisper[iii], of course as a flex for the internet community.
What I looked at was Freenet[iv] and Retroshare[v] but they don't seem to work like Wuala and the availability and speeds seem to be low. Also DC++[vi] and eMule[vii] are only for connecting and retrieving information and sharing, not for uploading and storing. Filecoin[viii] + IPFS[ix] looked promising, but not free. Torrents are also for sharing files not for private storage.
Looked at awesome storage[xi] but nothing stood out with the below requirements.
So what I'm looking for is:

Future proof
Open Source
Freeware aka Gratis
Linux Windows Mac
Distributed storage
Distributed discussion groups
2+ TiB free storage, willing to share storage for others to get storage
With tests coverage
High speed connections
With a vibrant community


[i] https://github.com/Significant-Gravitas/AutoGPT/blob/f9b8b0a41a827d5208b25d3e9e5f620b1441301d/docs/content/server/ollama.md?plain=1#L4
[ii] https://ollama.com/library?sort=popular
[iii] https://github.com/openai/whisper
[iv] [https://freenet.org/
[v] https://retroshare.cc/
[vi] https://sourceforge.net/projects/strongdc/
[vii] https://www.emule-project.com/home/perl/general.cgi?l=1
[viii] https://filecoin.io/store/#storage
[ix] https://ipfs.tech/ 
[x] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wuala
[xi] https://github.com/okhosting/awesome-storage

Please leave a comment if you know such a software and anytime in the future if and when it gets built, appreciate it.
